# Latex Multiline Equations

Tags: latex, alignment, multiline

Is it possible to get multline like behavior within a gather 
environment?  I have a set of equations in a gather environment, but 
one of them is too long, and I'd like to split it up onto two lines 
where the first line is left-aligned and the second line is right-aligned 
(just like multline).  If there is a way of aligning individual lines 
within the gather or split environment (like flushleft or flushright but 
functional in mathmode) this would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `mathtools` package has an inner `multlined` environment similar to `gathered` and the likes, but it required a small amount of manual tweaking:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

% \begin{multline}
%   \framebox[0.65\linewidth]{\strut} \\
%   \framebox[0.6\linewidth]{\strut} \\
%   \framebox[0.65\linewidth]{\strut} \\
%   \framebox[0.6\linewidth]{\strut}
% \end{multline}

\begin{gather}
  \framebox[0.8\linewidth]{\strut} \\
  \begin{multlined}[b][\linewidth-3\multlinegap]
    \framebox[0.65\linewidth]{\strut} \\
    \framebox[0.6\linewidth]{\strut} \\
    \framebox[0.65\linewidth]{\strut} \\
    \framebox[0.6\linewidth]{\strut}
  \end{multlined} \\
  \framebox[0.4\linewidth]{\strut}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you can try putting \hfill in front of the second line.

Having said that: IMHO, multline behavior inside a gather environment is undesirable. Especially if you have the fleqn option enabled, you should consider the following option:
put the long equation inside a split, with alignment on the left side of the equality. Assuming the right hand side is too long, put its second part on a new line (still inside the split) and use \hspace{1cm} (or some other length) to indent the second part a bit further.

For an overview of all AMS multiline blocks, see [the amsmath documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf).

Comment: Unfortunately \hfill doesn't seem to work... normally I'd agree that aligning equals signs looks better, however in my case I have a series of equalities that differ drastically in how much is on either side of the equality, making things look very unbalanced (as one line sticks way out from the line before).  Within this context, a multline like behavior would look best for a line that is too long  for the page.